# Map the version history in WSS as network drive

Tags: network-share, wss, versioning

I believe I once saw that it was possible to share versions of documents in WSS like the library itself.

e.g. when the path is like

http://myShare/SomeDocuments

then it was like

http://myShare/SomeDocuments/versions/1

or something like that ... I can't find information about it. Do I recall that right, is it possible at all and how do I do it?